# Bipartite Graph With Weighted Edges

Tags: computer-science, bipartite

I have a problem where I have a bipartite graph with weighted edges. What I want to do is sum the weights of the edges incident on every vertice, for each vertice individually.

The eventual goal is to convert the weights incident on every vertice into a %, and use a confidence interval to carry out certain operations.

I'm currently approaching this problem by building an adjacency matrix to represent the bipartite graph. I intend to iterate over one set of nodes of the graph, and update the relevant cells in the matrix with the weight of the connecting edge.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

*Note: I am not looking for a 1:1 matching algorithm like the Hungarian algorithm. I have no need to find a match, just a % based on the weights of the edges.*

Comment: Is there a restriction on how the bi-partite graph is stored? If not, you could store the weights, instead of 1s, in the adjacency matrix and then do a row-sum.

Comment: No, there is no restriction on how the graph is stored. However, I need information on nodes from both sets of the bipartite graph. For instance, if I look for the top 75% matches based on weights, I need info on nodes from both sets that fulfill this criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a bipartite graph with 5 vertices and two vertex sets U = {v1, v2, v3} and V = {v4, v5}.Note that, in any bipartite, there will be no edges between elements of the same vertex set e.g., v1 and v2 or v4 and v5. 
 [image: Bi-partite graph] 
 So you could construct an adjacency matrix with vertices from U as rows and vertices from V as columns:

```
        v4  v5   |sum(w)
                 |
    v1  0   7    | 7
                 | 
    v2  6   0    | 6 
                 |
    v3  10  2    | 12
__________________
sum(w)  16  9
```

This way a row-sum will give you the sum of weights of the edges incident on a vertex in U and a column-sum will be on a vertex in V. 
 
 Hope that helps!